# What is the difference between New Code feature in Sonarqube 8.9 Community edition and the Developer edition

Tags: sonarqube

I would like to know the major difference between New Code feature in Sonarqube Community edition and the Developer edition. I browsed the internet but couldn't get any segregation on the features.

Comment: Have you referred this [Defining New Code](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/new-code-period/) You can see the clear difference between the Community and Developer edition related to **New Code** feature

Comment: yes I am referring to that.

Comment: As @SouravAtta pointed out: the main difference is that Developer Edition and above supports branches and the Community does not, so you will not be able to select anything that refers to branches in Community Edition.

Comment: it is mentioned, "For Community Edition, past analysis is available at the project-level because Community Edition doesn't support multiple branches." So will CE support a single branch if the project has only one?